# How to align a label vertically in apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to align text vertically in a label.

This doesn't work :

```
.setStyleAttribute("verticalAlign","bottom")
```

Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `vertical-align` instead of `verticalAlign` as `setStyleAttribute()` uses CSS to display.

However, it doesn't seem to work despite that. Labels have a `setHorizontalAlignment()` method but no `setVerticalAlignment()` method.

The above two facts makes me think that vertical alignment is not allowed in widgets such as a Label or it might be a bug. It is probably worth opening an issue in the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list)

Comment: I opened an Issue: 2963 https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2963

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are confusing the Label with the Panel, if so then what you are trying to do is to align the label in the panel. Do so like this:

```
panel.setHeight(100)
.setVerticalAlignment(UiApp.VerticalAlignment.BOTTOM).add(label);
```

To clarify (in a flow-layout) the size of the label is automatically the same size as the text, so it would not usually make sense to align the text inside of the label unless you had already re-sized the label. The flow-layout is what is used in VerticalPanel and HorizontalPanel.

The CSS "label.setStyleAttribute('vertical-align','bottom');" that I've tried did NOT work, so I'm guessing we would need to dig into the GWT for a more literal solution to this question. I would be interested to see one. For more info checkout the objects in the [GAS API](http://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/label) or [GWT Panels](http://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/label), or let me know if I missed something relevant.